# Calling functions when parameter is value or reference type in C#?

Tags: c#

```
public class A
{
void methodA(int a){}
void methodA(ref int a){}
}

 static void Main()
  {
    int a=1;
    new classA().methodA(a);
  }
```

In Main class, which method is called? Are methods in class A are overloaded? can overriding is possible on the bases of value or reference parameters? Please help out to make me clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fixing your code:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public void methodA(int a) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Without ref");
    }

    public void methodA(ref int a) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("With ref");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 1;
        var a = new ClassA();

        a.methodA(i);
        a.methodA(ref i);

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

You'll see that the first call will print 'Without ref' and the second 'With ref'. You could've done this yourself.

The [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says it's perfectly possible:

> However, overloading can be done when one method has a ref or out parameter and the other has a value parameter, as shown in the following example.
>
> ```
> class RefOverloadExample
> {
>     public void SampleMethod(int i) { }
>     public void SampleMethod(ref int i) { }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
new A().methodA(a);
```

will call the non-`ref` version.

```
new A().methodA(ref a);
```

will call the `ref` version.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you have to explicitly say if you're passing by reference.

Following calls are different

```
int a = 5;
methodA(a);
methodA(ref a );
```

Answer (score 0):

[ref keyword MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

> **overloading can be done when one method has a ref or out** parameter and
>   the other has a value parameter, as shown in the following example

In your case it will call `methodA(int a){}` not the one with ref.

Your class should be:

```
public class A
{
    public void methodA(int a) 
    { 
    }
    public void methodA(ref int a) 
    { 
    }
}
```

If you want to call the overloaded method with `ref` keyword you need to specify `ref` in your method call. Like:

```
int a = 1;
A classAObj = new A();
classAObj.methodA(ref a);
```

The above code will resolved to the overloaded `methodA(ref a)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A
{
void methodA(int a){}
void methodA(ref int a){}
}

 static void Main()
  {
    int a=1;
    new classA().methodA(a);
    new classA().methodA(ref a)//You can add this to see the difference

  }
```

Both are different from each other...

```
new classA().methodA(a);
new classA().methodA(ref a)
```